# How do you pass level 3?

Tags: vim-adventures

I am playing a web based game called [VIM Adventures](http://vim-adventures.com) but I am getting stuck on level 3.

I get stuck in the infinite loop maze:

[image]

How do you pass level 3 in VIM Adventures?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `w` and `e` to navigate the maze. You should be able to use `w` (forward by a word) to get to "on," but since the next `w` should take you to "and" but the first letter is blocked, use `e` (end of word) instead. Similarly you won't be able to use `e` on "friend" since the last letter is blocked.

A simple way to get to the end is to spam `w` until you hear the beep, then switch to `e`, et cetera. Once you pick up the tile at the end that allows you to use `x`, you can return to the previous area to rub out the red letters. Since the maze was timed, I just let it teleport me back after a while.

(And once you do that, you can return to the initial maze to unlock that chest there using all your new powers.)

Comment: Oooh, the *first* maze! With the chest! I didn't think of that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Go back and use  the **X** to delete the red words.